# runtime error in following pascal code

Tags: pascal, prime-factoring

I am trying to factor a given number `a`, so I have written the following Pascal code:

```
program prime_factors;
  var b:array[1..1000] of integer;
  k,i,d,a:integer;
begin
  k:=0;
  write(' enter number ');
  read(a);
  while a>1 do
    if a mod d =0 then
      begin
        k:=k+1;
        b[k]:=d;
        a:=a div d;
      end
    else
      if d=2 then
        d:=d+1
      else
        d:=d+2;
   for i:=1 to k do
     write(b[i],'  ');
   readln();
   readln();
end.
```

But when I run it, it gives me error 200 or runtime error, but I can't determine what is problem. I have used k as length of numbers of factors in b array.  Should I think what problem is with index k?

Comment: found my error,i have not  initialized d

Comment: Each runtime error code has an associated description. Error 200 is division by zero, which should reveal that d is indeed the culprit, since all division operations (mod, div) in your code use d as the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

you should define D:=2; right after the Begin :D because it's default value is 0.